# how to locate row in dataframe without headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I noticed that when using .loc in pandas dataframe, it not only finds the row of data I am looking for but also includes the header column names of the dataframe I am searching within.

So when I try to append the .loc row of data, it includes the data + column headers - I don't want any column headers!

```
##1st dataframe
df_futures.head(1)
date     max    min
19990101 2000   1900

##2nd dataframe
df_cash.head(1)
date$   max$   min$
1999101 50     40

##if date is found in dataframe 2, I will collect the row of data
data_to_track = []

for ii in range(len(df_futures['date'])):
    ##date I will try to find in df2
    date_to_find = df_futures['date'][ii]

    ##append the row of data to my list
    data_to_track.append(df_cash.loc[df_cash['Date$'] == date_to_find])
```

I want the for loop to return just 19990101  50  40

It currently returns  0 19990101 50  40, date$, max$, min$

Comment: First, you want to `merge` both dataframes on columns `Date$` and `date`. We can be of more help if you show us complete dataframe structure.

Comment: I don't see a use of `iloc`, just `loc`.

Comment: You should try to explain the problem a little bit better.

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear - hopefully I have clarified it better.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with other comments regarding the clarity of the question. However, if what you want to get is just a string that contains a particular row's data, then you could use `to_string()` method of Pandas.

In your case,

Instead of this:

```
df_cash.loc[df_cash['Date$'] == date_to_find]
```

You could get a string that includes only the row data:

```
df_cash[df_cash['Date$'] == date_to_find].to_string(header=None)
```

Also notice that I dropped the .loc part, which outputs the same result.

If your dataframe has multiple columns and you dont want them to be joined in a string (may bring data type issues and is potentially problematic if you want to separate them later on), you could use list() method such as:

```
list(df_cash[df_cash['Date$'] == date_to_find].iloc[0])
```